# Catch UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning during fetch

Tags: javascript, try-catch, es6-promise

I have a code:

```
function () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      fetch(URL, { method: METHOD, body: BODY })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((json) => {
          resolve(json);
        })
        .catch((res) => {
          reject(res);
        })
    } catch (exception) {
      reject(exception);
    }
  });
}
```

When server responses not with json I've got

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().

I know that try-catch do not catch async throws.

I have read

[Cannot catch UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning in promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46571730/cannot-catch-unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-in-promise),

[Try Catch unable to catch UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50963104/try-catch-unable-to-catch-unhandledpromiserejectionwarning),

[“UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning” error even when catch is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46738830/unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-error-even-when-catch-is-present)

but there is no answer for my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Try catch` will not be able to handle error which is thrown asynchronously (i.e, in promise), you must use `.catch()` for that.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4zgvtxh/)

```
function someFunc() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        fetch(URL, {method: METHOD, body: BODY})
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((json) => {
                resolve(json);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                reject(err);
            })
    });
}

someFunc()
.then((value)=>{})
.catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})
```

Edit:
 When the server responds with no `json` but with error, your returned promise is `rejected`. Therefore, you should make sure that you are calling `.catch()` on your function call (i.e, `someFunc().catch(()=>{})`). This error comes up if have left your rejected promise unhandled (without catch).

Edit2: Oops. Sorry, misread your question but I guess explanation remains same.
If `res` is not having `json()` method over it, it will throw the following error when you call `res.json()`::

```
Uncaught TypeError: res.json() is not a function
```

This `error` will be caught by your `.catch()` block. **Now catch block will return a new rejected promise.** When the function is called and if there is no `catch()` to handle the request, the error which you are talking about will be thrown.

I have explained a bit more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51011826/value-of-promise-all-after-it-is-rejected-shows-promisestatus-resolved/51013221#51013221).

Comment: nope, didnt help. I think unhandled rejection is here `res.json()`

Comment: @SashaKos Please see Edit2

Comment: Thanks for help, but the question is still open. `res` always has `json()` method because it is a part of ES6 `fetch` API. But by some reasons  json parsing error in `json()`  does not catch by `catch(() => ...)`, may be bacause nesting..

Comment: @SashaKos Are you sure json parsing error is not being caught by `.catch()`?  That would be very weird. Can you console.log  into catch block and confirm that?

Comment: It DID catch by `.catch()`, but, there is also a warning

Comment: How stupid i was. I didnt have CATCH here someFunc().then((value)=>{}).CATCH((err)=>{console.log(err)})

Answer (score 0):

Try/catch only works for asynchronous actions when wrapping it with an async function.

```
fetchSomething = async url => {
  try {
     await fetch(url)
  } catch (error) {
     // We will see error here
  }
}
```

See others ways to catch async error here: https://dev.to/sobiodarlington/better-error-handling-with-async-await-2e5m

Comment: link to docs maybe, or other explanation of this pattern? why does this work?

Comment: We can see a lot of samples to catch asynchronous here: https://dev.to/sobiodarlington/better-error-handling-with-async-await-2e5m

Comment: Done! Thanks @danimal